# Where can I find a gun as quickly as possible?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I was told this game has guns. But I've been playing for *hours* and seen absolutely no sign of one. Where can I acquire a gun for what I had hoped to make into my badass new [Wizard With A Shotgun?](http://gunshowcomic.com/comics/20081015.gif)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually a Unique Pistol available right on the very first map of the tutorial section of the game!

To find it, you'll need to have at least 1 point in Mechanics Skill after character creation. That means you'll need to be playing as a **Cipher**, **Chanter**, **Rogue**, or **Wizard**, ***OR***, you'll need to select the **Laborer**, **Merchant**, or **Scientist** background. Any *one* of these options will give you at least one point of Mechanics.

Then, after you've been assigned a bodyguard and told to go look for berries, head for the far Southwestern corner of the map; the weird campfire, across the bridge near the stream:

[image: Map]

Once there, take a closer look at the tent - you'll need to turn on **Scouting Mode** (i.e. Stealth), and move around in the area a bit - soon your character will notice something, and a new (hilit in purple when you tab hilight) container will appear:

[image: Hidden Cache]

You'll find The Disappointer! It... lives up to it's name, unfortunately:

[image: Disappointer Stats and Description]

Answer (score 4):

For something a little less disappointing, when you pick up Kana from Caed Nua, he comes equipped with an Arquebus:

[image]

Comment: And to the south at Anslög's Compass, there's a Fine Pistol in a hidden cache in the Spore Cave.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFIzz This has been changed to a fine wand in later patches

Answer (score 2):

The Disappointer pistol may be enchanted with something cheap, if kept, to remove the bad attributes.

Also, in version 2.00, a Pistol can be looted from the corpse of the Backer NPC 'Sidi Exa', located in White March, near Madhmr Bridge and south of Black Meadow.

This NPC is not important, but killing him does drop your reputation with Defiance Bay by a small amount. You can circumvent this by equipping all of your party members with ranged weapons, positioning yourself just to the south of Peregund (out of her field of view), and killing Sidi from there.