# Is the Disappointer good for anything?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

The Disappointer is a Very Bad Gun:

[image: You might even call it... Terrible.]

I mean, it even has a special property of **Terrible**; -8 accuracy and damage reduced by a third is, in fact, very very bad. Is the gun actually useful for anything other than being [a gun that you can get right away?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/211355/)

Answer (score 4):

**As of Patch 1.0.3, this is still *probably* the optimal thing to do, but it's nowhere near as great as it used to be. Feel free to just hold on to the crappy gun and shoot things with it if you want, I guess.**

You can sell it to an unsuspecting dupe of a merchant who will overpay you for it! It sells for quite a bit of cash, so long as you sell it *immediately*. Specifically, Heodan, in the Caravan Encampment in the tutorial is a fairly incompetent merchant. He will buy your things for *substantially* more than they are worth in many cases. For example, he will give you 75 cp for some clothing that is worth next to nothing. Even better though, he will give you *150* cp for The Disappointer. That's a lot of scratch for just starting out in the Dyrwood.

The trick is that this means you need to retrieve the gun and sell it to Heodan *before* triggering the ambush at the stream, (i.e. before interacting with the waterskins found near where you'll pick up The Disappointer). This isn't a big deal, but it's a thing to be conscious of.

Comment: What's the actual steps to get the Disappointer? I thought I explored everything before the ambush and I didn't know it was a thing. Is it a starting pistol for a class or do you get it in the actual world? EDIT: Nevermind, answered in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211355/where-can-i-find-a-gun-as-quickly-as-possible

Answer (score 1):

The Disappointer is not useless... because you can remove the "terrible" attribute by enchanting it. (Damage, accuracy, fine, any of the first set of enchantments replaces an existing condition enchantment.)

I really wanted to use a pistol for my character concept, and so I stubbornly kept using this gun even though I missed all the time (on hard difficulty... yeah, okay, I did a lot of reloading) but just after leaving the first village I got enough components to give it a damage enchantment, and that boosted the damage from 65% to 115% and removed the accuracy penalty. Now it one-shots some of the enemies I meet at level 5 and really puts the hurt on the rest.

Where to find it:
It's in concealed in one of the tents after you cross the bridge in the starter area. You may need some skill to find it, I'm not sure. (Edit: you need 1 rank in Mechanics.) You definitely need to be in stealth/detect mode.

Comment: Reportedly, this no longer works as of the newest patch.

Answer (score 0):

In [Story Time mode](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Mode) and playing as a Cipher, I use the Disappointer as my main weapon throughout Act I. With my poor sample size, I still find the gun very useful indeed especially once enchanted. It seems to hit 2/3 of the time.

Although, I am fairly sure it has something to do with the game mechanics being biased in the player's favour more than lucky dice rolls.